# thinking about having sex

Tags: quran

I am an unmarried girl. I do not watch vulgar movies/ shows. I do not live with persons who always talk about sex or staff like that. But still I can not stop myself thinking about having sex and sexual fantasies. In our culture it is not possible for me to get married right now. I just do not want to think about it. My question is how big is my sin? Is thinking about it haram? Please let me know and please suggest me how can I control myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you don't act upon it or tell about it, you won't be punished because they are just thoughts, it's humans nature and totally normal.
BUT thinking too much about sex is the opposite of Chastity, which could lead to the act of sin, so you should try to controll that, I had (and still have) the same problem and trust me the first and last and best solution, since you are not married, is to get busy, do things, keep yourself and your mind busy, because once we have free time, once we set with nothing to do, those thoughts come again, at least that's how it is in my case.

Comment: thank you very much , may Allah help us all.